Unable to reach web applications running on AKS cluster after routing traffic through Azure Firewall
After associating the subnet where the AKS Nodes run I am unable to reach any of the hostnames stated in the ingress objects even after updating the DNS Zone records to the Public IP of the Firewall.
The AKS Cluster already has an nginx ingress controller working with a Public Load Balancer. The nginx ingress controller is managed by ArgoCD running on the AKS cluster. I started by creating an additional subnet called AzureFirewallSubnet in the AKS's vnet. After that a Firewall, Policy, Public IP, and Route Table.
The Route Table has the following Route



Address Prefix
Next Hop Type
Next Hop Ip Address




0.0.0.0/0
Virtual Application
Firewall Private IP



The Firewall has DNS proxy enabled and is using the default Azure DNS Server
The Firewall Policy has the following Rules Collection:
AKSEgressRuleCollection Priority 500
Application Rules Priority 500



Source
Protocol
Destination
Action




*
http,https
*
Allow



Network Rules Priority 400



Source
Protocol
Destination
Action




*
Any
IPs: *
Allow


*
Any
ServiceTags: AzureAD, ACR, MCR
Allow



I edited the values file of the ingress controller to create an internal load balancer instead of  using the public load balancer
controller:
  service:
    # externalTrafficPolicy: Local
    # omitClusterIP: "true" 
    # loadBalancerIP: LB_PUBLIC_IP

    labels: 
      app: nginx-ingress
    
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: "my-aks-subnet"
      # service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: my-aks-resource-group
      # service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path: "/healthz"

After confirming that the changes were applied I associated the Route Table to the aks-subnet and added the following DNAT rule to AKSEgressRuleCollection.
DNAT Rules Priority 100



Source
Protocol
Destination Port
Destination IP
Translated IP
Translated Port




*
TCP
443
Firewall Public IP
Internal LB private IP
80



Next I went to the Public DNS Zone that manages the ingress hosts and updated the A record of the argocd ingress host to the Public IP of the Firewall instead of the Public Load Balancer. However I am unable to reach the ArgoCD UI.
This is the spec of the ingress controller service
spec:
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    nodePort: 32167
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    nodePort: 30945
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: LB_PRIVATE_IP
      ipMode: VIP

This is the spec ingress of the ArgoCD server
spec:
  rules:
  - host: argocd.my.dns.zone.net
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: argocd-server
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - secretName: letsencrypt-prod-new-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: LB_PRIVATE_IP

What have I missed or am doing wrong ?

Verify that the subnet where the internal load balancer resides (AKS subnet) is configured to allow incoming traffic from the Azure Firewall's subnet and also change the DNAT rule to translate port 443 on the firewall's public IP directly to port 443 on the ILB (the ingress controller) rather than port 80.

Currently there's no NSG how else can I check that ILB allows incoming traffic from the AzureFirewallSubnet  ?

I see, then check if the AKS ILB is reachable from the Azure Firewall's subnet do a curl -k https://<ILB_Private_IP>
